# What CRUD resources should be provided for a database template table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, crud

Imagine a web application to track assignments for reading multiple books at once. For instance, if books A & B have 16 chapters and book C has 32 chapters, then to complete all three books in 16 weeks a person would need to read 1 chapter per week for books A & B and 2 chapters per week for book C.

When a user creates their own reading plan, the application would copy the reading plan template to create actual assignments for each week. Each assignment would contain a due date based on the user provided start date. Each assignment would also be linked on a one-to-many basis to each chapter to be read that week, so that the user can track their progress on a per chapter basis for each of the four chapters required to be read each week.

[image]

### Questions

- Should I provide the Create CRUD resource for assignments, even though users won't create individual assignments?
- Should I just provide the Create CRUD resource for a reading plan, which would then go through and copy the template assignments to that user's reading plan assignments?

This is a Ruby on Rails 3.1 application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are really strapped for time/resources, I'd suggest to provide direct CRUD functionalities, even if they may perhaps restricted to some admin/superuser profile.

No matter how brilliantly designed, an application sooner or later will need some quick&dirty bypass functionality to directly amend data at a lower level, in my experience.

Comment: I agree completely. There's always something that comes up somewhere down the line where root user needs quick and dirty access to CRUD functionality like this. Scaffolding out all this stuff would be a breeze, anyway, so why not? You can always add auth to the crud functionality to restrict access, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should focus the User Experience (UX) on what the users want/need to do: creating `reading plans.`

Users don't care (and shouldn't need to care) about your internal architectural modeling of the business problem.

A common model for complicated input is the "wizard" which steps the user through a number of sequential steps as they fill out small forms or answer questions. That may be of help here.

You might want additional crud interfaces to various tables for your own administrative uses. But for the users themselves, focus on their view of the problem, not your view of it.

If they think of a reading plan of consisting of a number of assignments, then the assignments could be visible to them as part of the plan. -- But put the assignments as expandable sections on a single html page per reading plan--people have a hard time maintaining mental state between screens.